# “Saying sorry won't make you smaller”,

Tags: adjectives, nouns, parts-of-speech

> “Saying **sorry** won't make you smaller”.

I'm not sure whether my question is reasonable or not but I was discussing this question with my friends, and got some points by them. We, actually, faced some challenges while deciding what PART OF SPEECH the word SORRY is in the given sentence!

Some of them called it as a NOUN and some of them called it as an ADJECTIVE.

I myself looked it up in different dictionaries, got answers as SORRY isn't used as a noun but an adjective.

Answer (score -1):

In this sentence, "sorry" is actually a quoted word, and it can be anything. I can even be an entire sentence.

> Saying **"Tomorrow will rain"** will not make you smaller.

However, in different sentences, it is an adjective (possibly with the value of an adverb).

> I am **sorry**.

The noun associated with "sorry" is most likely "apology".

> Please accept my <strike>**sorries**</strike>.
>
> Please accept my **apologies**.

---

"Sorry" can be used as a noun as in the joke below:

> - I am Sorry.
> - Nice to meet you. I am John.

Comment: It means that in the given sentence, SORRY can be an adverb or adjective, right?

Comment: I am not sure if (strictly speaking) it is an adverb - because the dictionaries tell that it is only adjective. But it is definitely not a noun.

Comment: Yes. If anyone wants to ask us for citing certified references then what we can do! No any dictionaries state that it's a NOUN.